# JPA sequence generator not working

Tags: java, oracle, jpa

Trying to setup an id with a JPA sequence generator:

```
@Entity 
@Table(name=CommitmentRegisterDetailTable.TABLE)
public class TestCrd {

    @Id 
    @Column(name=CommitmentRegisterDetailTable.COMMIT_REG_DETAIL_ID)
    @SequenceGenerator(name="CRD_ID", sequenceName="COMMIT_REG_DETAIL_ID_SEQ", allocationSize=1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="CRD_ID")
    private int id;

    @Column(name=CommitmentRegisterDetailTable.COMMIT_REG_ID)
    private int commitRegId = 89915;
}
```

With this entity I am able to do load, and merge. But when I do persist(), the SQL output shows it attempts to perform an INSERT with id = 0. Am I missing a step?

This is an Oracle DB.

Code where I persist:

```
    TestCrd testCrd = new TestCrd();

    EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory( "incepPersistence" );
    EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager();

    em.getTransaction().begin();

    em.persist( testCrd );

    em.getTransaction().commit();
    em.close();
    factory.close();
```

Sequence details:

```
CREATED 07-JUN-16
LAST_DDL_TIME   07-JUN-16
SEQUENCE_OWNER  RMS
SEQUENCE_NAME   COMMIT_REG_DETAIL_ID_SEQ
MIN_VALUE   0
MAX_VALUE   999999999999999999999999999
INCREMENT_BY    1
CYCLE_FLAG  N
ORDER_FLAG  N
CACHE_SIZE  0
LAST_NUMBER 107568
```

This is the call that goes to the DB. As you can see the first parameter COMMIT_REG_DETAIL_ID is assigned a value of 0.

```
Call: INSERT INTO RMS.COMMITMENT_REGISTER_DETAIL (COMMIT_REG_DETAIL_ID, AMOUNT, COMMITTED, LINE_DESCRIPTION, DISBURSED, INVOICED, LINE_NUMBER, OBLIGATED, RECEIVED, ACCOUNT_COMBO_ID, COMMIT_REG_ID, OBJECT_CLASS_CODE, SP_DETAIL_VALUE_ID) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
bind => [0, 5127, null, null, null, null, 0, null, null, 2097, 89843, 31510, null]
Query: InsertObjectQuery(com.incep.commitmentregister.CommitmentRegisterDetail@2ee77e0f)
```

Here's the full JPA log set to FINEST:

```
[EL Finest]: jpa: 2016-07-06 13:56:00.506--ServerSession(786709615)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Begin predeploying Persistence Unit incepPersistence; session file:/D:/Development/Workspaces/InCEP/incep-aspr-aqc-local/codeCharge/WEB-INF/classes/_incepPersistence; state Initial; factoryCount 0
[EL Finest]: properties: 2016-07-06 13:56:00.535--ServerSession(786709615)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--property=eclipselink.orm.throw.exceptions; default value=true
[EL Finest]: properties: 2016-07-06 13:56:00.536--ServerSession(786709615)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--property=eclipselink.weaving.changetracking; default value=true
[EL Finest]: properties: 2016-07-06 13:56:00.536--ServerSession(786709615)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--property=eclipselink.weaving.lazy; default value=true
[EL Finest]: properties: 2016-07-06 13:56:00.536--ServerSession(786709615)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--property=eclipselink.weaving.eager; default value=false
[EL Finest]: properties: 2016-07-06 13:56:00.537--ServerSession(786709615)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--property=eclipselink.weaving.fetchgroups; default value=true
[EL Finest]: properties: 2016-07-06 13:56:00.537--ServerSession(786709615)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--property=eclipselink.weaving.internal; default value=true
[EL Finest]: properties: 2016-07-06 13:56:00.539--ServerSession(786709615)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--property=eclipselink.multitenant.tenants-share-emf; default value=true
[EL Finest]: properties: 2016-07-06 13:56:00.539--ServerSession(786709615)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--property=eclipselink.multitenant.tenants-share-cache; default value=false
[EL Finer]: metadata: 2016-07-06 13:56:00.573--ServerSession(786709615)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Searching for default mapping file in file:/D:/Development/Workspaces/InCEP/incep-aspr-aqc-local/codeCharge/WEB-INF/classes/ (There is no English translation for this message.)
[EL Finer]: metadata: 2016-07-06 13:56:00.976--ServerSession(786709615)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Found a default mapping file at file:/D:/Development/Workspaces/InCEP/incep-aspr-aqc-local/codeCharge/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/orm.xml for root URL file:/D:/Development/Workspaces/InCEP/incep-aspr-aqc-local/codeCharge/WEB-INF/classes/ (There is no English translation for this message.)
[EL Finer]: metadata: 2016-07-06 13:56:02.326--ServerSession(786709615)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Searching for default mapping file in file:/D:/Development/Workspaces/InCEP/incep-aspr-aqc-local/codeCharge/WEB-INF/classes/ (There is no English translation for this message.)
[EL Config]: metadata: 2016-07-06 13:56:02.775--ServerSession(786709615)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--The access type for the persistent class [class com.incep.test.commitmentregister.TestCrd] is set to [FIELD].
[EL Config]: metadata: 2016-07-06 13:56:02.815--ServerSession(786709615)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--The alias name for the entity class [class com.incep.test.commitmentregister.TestCrd] is being defaulted to: TestCrd.
[EL Finer]: weaver: 2016-07-06 13:56:02.889--ServerSession(786709615)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Class [com.incep.test.commitmentregister.TestCrd] registered to be processed by weaver.
[EL Finest]: jpa: 2016-07-06 13:56:02.898--ServerSession(786709615)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--End predeploying Persistence Unit incepPersistence; session file:/D:/Development/Workspaces/InCEP/incep-aspr-aqc-local/codeCharge/WEB-INF/classes/_incepPersistence; state Predeployed; factoryCount 0
[EL Finer]: weaver: 2016-07-06 13:56:02.899--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--JavaSECMPInitializer - transformer is null.
[EL Finest]: jpa: 2016-07-06 13:56:02.9--ServerSession(786709615)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Begin predeploying Persistence Unit incepPersistence; session file:/D:/Development/Workspaces/InCEP/incep-aspr-aqc-local/codeCharge/WEB-INF/classes/_incepPersistence; state Predeployed; factoryCount 0
[EL Finest]: jpa: 2016-07-06 13:56:02.901--ServerSession(786709615)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--End predeploying Persistence Unit incepPersistence; session file:/D:/Development/Workspaces/InCEP/incep-aspr-aqc-local/codeCharge/WEB-INF/classes/_incepPersistence; state Predeployed; factoryCount 1
[EL Finest]: jpa: 2016-07-06 13:56:22.435--ServerSession(786709615)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Begin deploying Persistence Unit incepPersistence; session file:/D:/Development/Workspaces/InCEP/incep-aspr-aqc-local/codeCharge/WEB-INF/classes/_incepPersistence; state Predeployed; factoryCount 1
[EL Finer]: 2016-07-06 13:56:22.453--ServerSession(786709615)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Could not initialize Validation Factory. Encountered following exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/validation/Validation
[EL Finest]: properties: 2016-07-06 13:56:22.481--ServerSession(786709615)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--property=eclipselink.logging.logger; value=DefaultLogger; translated value=org.eclipse.persistence.logging.DefaultSessionLog
[EL Finest]: properties: 2016-07-06 13:56:22.482--ServerSession(786709615)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--property=eclipselink.logging.level; value=FINEST; translated value=FINEST
[EL Finest]: properties: 2016-07-06 13:56:22.483--ServerSession(786709615)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--property=eclipselink.logging.level; value=FINEST; translated value=FINEST
[EL Finest]: properties: 2016-07-06 13:56:22.484--ServerSession(786709615)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--property=eclipselink.target-database; value=org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.oracle.OraclePlatform
[EL Finest]: properties: 2016-07-06 13:56:22.493--ServerSession(786709615)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--property=eclipselink.id-validation; value=NULL
[EL Finest]: properties: 2016-07-06 13:56:22.493--ServerSession(786709615)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--property=eclipselink.session.customizer; value=com.apprio.acquisition.JPAEclipseLinkSessionCustomizer
_JPAEclipseLinkSessionCustomizer: configured java:comp/env/jdbc/OracleRMS_DS
[EL Info]: 2016-07-06 13:56:22.496--ServerSession(786709615)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.4.1.v20121003-ad44345
[EL Config]: connection: 2016-07-06 13:56:22.509--ServerSession(786709615)--Connection(1167290948)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--connecting(DatabaseLogin(
    platform=>OraclePlatform
    user name=> ""
    connector=>JNDIConnector datasource name=>java:comp/env/jdbc/OracleRMS_DS
))
[EL Config]: connection: 2016-07-06 13:56:23.129--ServerSession(786709615)--Connection(452044444)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Connected: jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:INCEPDEV
    User: RMS
    Database: Oracle  Version: Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production
    Driver: Oracle JDBC driver  Version: 11.2.0.2.0
[EL Finest]: connection: 2016-07-06 13:56:23.143--ServerSession(786709615)--Connection(839511213)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Connection acquired from connection pool [read].
[EL Finest]: connection: 2016-07-06 13:56:23.144--ServerSession(786709615)--Connection(839511213)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Connection released to connection pool [read].
[EL Config]: connection: 2016-07-06 13:56:23.144--ServerSession(786709615)--Connection(697396101)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--connecting(DatabaseLogin(
    platform=>OraclePlatform
    user name=> ""
    connector=>JNDIConnector datasource name=>java:comp/env/jdbc/OracleRMS_DS
))
[EL Config]: connection: 2016-07-06 13:56:23.31--ServerSession(786709615)--Connection(170524181)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Connected: jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:INCEPDEV
    User: RMS
    Database: Oracle  Version: Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production
    Driver: Oracle JDBC driver  Version: 11.2.0.2.0
[EL Finest]: sequencing: 2016-07-06 13:56:23.327--ServerSession(786709615)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--sequencing connected, state is Preallocation_NoTransaction_State
[EL Finest]: sequencing: 2016-07-06 13:56:23.327--ServerSession(786709615)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--sequence COMMIT_REG_DETAIL_ID_SEQ: preallocation size 1
[EL Info]: connection: 2016-07-06 13:56:23.365--ServerSession(786709615)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--file:/D:/Development/Workspaces/InCEP/incep-aspr-aqc-local/codeCharge/WEB-INF/classes/_incepPersistence login successful
[EL Finer]: metamodel: 2016-07-06 13:56:23.441--ServerSession(786709615)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Canonical Metamodel class [com.incep.test.commitmentregister.TestCrd_] not found during initialization.
[EL Finest]: jpa: 2016-07-06 13:56:23.442--ServerSession(786709615)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--End deploying Persistence Unit incepPersistence; session file:/D:/Development/Workspaces/InCEP/incep-aspr-aqc-local/codeCharge/WEB-INF/classes/_incepPersistence; state Deployed; factoryCount 1
[EL Finer]: connection: 2016-07-06 13:56:29.205--ServerSession(786709615)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--client acquired: 1882760631
[EL Finer]: transaction: 2016-07-06 13:56:29.235--ClientSession(1882760631)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--acquire unit of work: 102009560
[EL Finest]: transaction: 2016-07-06 13:56:30.565--UnitOfWork(102009560)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--persist() operation called on: com.incep.test.commitmentregister.TestCrd@3c07590f.
[EL Finer]: transaction: 2016-07-06 13:56:33.25--UnitOfWork(102009560)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--begin unit of work commit
[EL Finest]: query: 2016-07-06 13:56:33.261--UnitOfWork(102009560)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Execute query InsertObjectQuery(com.incep.test.commitmentregister.TestCrd@3c07590f)
[EL Finest]: connection: 2016-07-06 13:56:33.267--ServerSession(786709615)--Connection(13402762)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Connection acquired from connection pool [default].
[EL Finer]: transaction: 2016-07-06 13:56:33.267--ClientSession(1882760631)--Connection(13402762)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--begin transaction
[EL Finest]: connection: 2016-07-06 13:56:33.268--ClientSession(1882760631)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--reconnecting to external connection pool
[EL Fine]: sql: 2016-07-06 13:56:33.557--ClientSession(1882760631)--Connection(1921921646)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--INSERT INTO RMS.COMMITMENT_REGISTER_DETAIL (COMMIT_REG_DETAIL_ID, COMMIT_REG_ID) VALUES (?, ?)
    bind => [0, 89915]
[EL Fine]: sql: 2016-07-06 13:56:33.9--ClientSession(1882760631)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--SELECT 1 FROM DUAL
[EL Warning]: 2016-07-06 13:56:33.927--UnitOfWork(102009560)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Local Exception Stack: 
Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.4.1.v20121003-ad44345): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-00001: unique constraint (RMS.COMMITMENT_REGISTER_DETAIL_PK) violated

Error Code: 1
Call: INSERT INTO RMS.COMMITMENT_REGISTER_DETAIL (COMMIT_REG_DETAIL_ID, COMMIT_REG_ID) VALUES (?, ?)
    bind => [0, 89915]
Query: InsertObjectQuery(com.incep.test.commitmentregister.TestCrd@3c07590f)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:324)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeDirectNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:851)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:913)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:594)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:537)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.basicExecuteCall(AbstractSession.java:1800)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ClientSession.executeCall(ClientSession.java:286)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:207)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.insertObject(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:342)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.StatementQueryMechanism.insertObject(StatementQueryMechanism.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.StatementQueryMechanism.insertObject(StatementQueryMechanism.java:177)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatabaseQueryMechanism.insertObjectForWrite(DatabaseQueryMechanism.java:471)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.InsertObjectQuery.executeCommit(InsertObjectQuery.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.InsertObjectQuery.executeCommitWithChangeSet(InsertObjectQuery.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatabaseQueryMechanism.executeWriteWithChangeSet(DatabaseQueryMechanism.java:286)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.WriteObjectQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(WriteObjectQuery.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:852)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(DatabaseQuery.java:751)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelModifyQuery.executeInUnitOfWorkObjectLevelModifyQuery(ObjectLevelModifyQuery.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelModifyQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(ObjectLevelModifyQuery.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:2875)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1602)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1584)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1535)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.CommitManager.commitNewObjectsForClassWithChangeSet(CommitManager.java:224)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.CommitManager.commitAllObjectsWithChangeSet(CommitManager.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.writeAllObjectsWithChangeSet(AbstractSession.java:3914)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitToDatabase(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1419)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.commitToDatabase(RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.java:634)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitToDatabaseWithChangeSet(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1509)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.commitRootUnitOfWork(RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.java:266)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitAndResume(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1147)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.transaction.EntityTransactionImpl.commitInternal(EntityTransactionImpl.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.transaction.EntityTransactionImpl.commit(EntityTransactionImpl.java:63)
    at com.incep.test.commitmentregister.TestCommitmentRegisterManager.testLoadSave(TestCommitmentRegisterManager.java:729)
    at com.incep.test.commitmentregister.TestCommitmentRegisterManager.testAll(TestCommitmentRegisterManager.java:73)
    at com.incep.test.TestMaster.testAll(TestMaster.java:54)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-00001: unique constraint (RMS.COMMITMENT_REGISTER_DETAIL_PK) violated

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:440)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:837)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:445)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:191)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:523)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:207)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForRows(T4CPreparedStatement.java:1010)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1315)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3576)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3657)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1350)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeDirectNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:842)
    ... 59 more

[EL Finer]: transaction: 2016-07-06 13:56:33.942--ClientSession(1882760631)--Connection(1921921646)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--rollback transaction
[EL Finest]: connection: 2016-07-06 13:56:33.966--ServerSession(786709615)--Connection(13402762)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Connection released to connection pool [default].
[EL Finer]: transaction: 2016-07-06 13:56:33.967--UnitOfWork(102009560)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--release unit of work
[EL Finer]: connection: 2016-07-06 13:56:33.967--ClientSession(1882760631)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--client released
```

Comment: can you post the source code for persisting?

Comment: Added persist code.

Comment: When the object is persisted, what calls go to the DB? That is what you have a JPA provider log for

Comment: I added the call to the DB from the log.

Comment: doesn't the database insert the actual sequence value for you? Did you check the actually inserted ID value in the DB?

Comment: That's what I'm expecting. The inserted ID value is 0. I can see it in the DB after it's been inserted. I get duplicate PK error if I try it again without removing the 0 row.

Comment: I could not reproduce with H2 DB, Could you try with Id as `Integer` instead of `int` also remove `allocationSize=1`?

Comment: allocationSize=1 is required to match the database sequence increment_by of 1, so shouldn't be changed.  If you turn logging to finest, you should see the provider attempt to obtain a sequence value before the insert statement - if this isn't happening, it might not be picking up your sequence annotations.  Check that you haven't mixed annotations on fields and properties - if you have, only one set will be picked up while the other will be ignored, or that you don't have an orm.xml file somewhere overriding your annotations.  Finest logging should help tell you what is (and isn't) happening.

Comment: I cleaned up the code to isolate the problem and I added the full jpa log set to finest.

Comment: @Holden Do you have a solution for this?

Comment: @amod yes, see my comment below regarding eclipselink.id-validation.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like I found my problem. Removing the ID validation property from persistence.xml appears to make the sequence work properly.

```
<property name="eclipselink.id-validation" value="NULL" />
```

Further update:

The way I ultimately managed to fix my problem is to leave the id validation as above, set to NULL. Meaning IDs with 0 do not throw error, but do not trigger the fetching of a new sequence on persist.

So I changed the id on my object from an int to an Integer object. When id is null, a new sequence id is fetched. When id is Integer(0), no error is thrown.

Answer (score 1):

Two case.

(1)

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int idx;
```

Auto_increment, sequence object -> strategy = GenerationType.AUTO

(2)
Your case.

> > Element Detail
>
> public abstract String **name** (Required) A unique generator name that
>   can be referenced by one or more classes to be the generator for
>   primary key values.
>
> public abstract String **sequenceName** (Optional) The name of the
>   database sequence object from which to obtain primary key values.
>   Defaults to a provider-chosen value. Default: hibernate_sequence
>
> public abstract int **initialValue** (Optional) The value from which the
>   sequence object is to start generating. Default:1
>
> public abstract int **allocationSize** (Optional) The amount to increment
>   by when allocating sequence numbers from the sequence. Default:50

DDL

```
create sequence RTDS_ADSINPUT_SEQ start with 1 increment by 1;
```

Entity

```
@Entity
@SequenceGenerator(
name = "CRD_ID", 
sequenceName = "RTDS_ADSINPUT_SEQ" 
initiaValue = 1, allocationSize = 1)
public class XXX {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "CRD_ID")
   private long id;

    //getter, setter
}
```

Comment: Thanks Byeon0gam. I don't know if you saw the previous suggested answer. Looks like my problem is related to the id validation property. When I remove it the generator works fine, but not when it's present. So I'm trying a workaround because I do have some entities that have been saved with id = 0 to the DB.

Comment: I have a question. you want to insert table in id value 0? Or you want sequence start with 0?  um. Your error : unique constraint (RMS.COMMITMENT_REGISTER_DETAIL_PK) violated. you check.

Comment: I want to insert with the next number in the sequence. The PK violation is because there's already an id = 0 row in the table (which there shouldn't be). JPA gets the next sequence number when the eclipselink.id-validation property is not present. When it is present it uses 0 and doesn't fetch the next sequence number. I cannot leave it not present because there are other tables that used an id = 0, so they would fail separately.

Comment: sorry. i late. you use one case. you can to insert with the next number in the sequence. it automation.